# Where to put files for testing with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am having a Rails application and I want to write some tests for it. It uses paperclip to attach images to a model. But now I want to know how to test this feature and how to use it in seeds.

Especially I want to know where the recommended place is to put the image files for seed/testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now:

```
photo_list = Dir.glob('./test/fixtures/files/images/*.jpg').entries

Person.all.each do |m|
  m.avatar = File.open(photo_list.pop)
  m.save!
end
```